# How can I find the allocation in a Haskell function compiled with GHC?

Tags: haskell, memory-management, ghc

I'm using GHC 7.4 to compile the following function:

```
nodups' :: [Int] -> Bool
nodups' = ok empty
  where ok _ [] = True
        ok seen (n:ns) = not (n `member` seen) && ok (n `insert` seen) ns
        member n word = testBit word n
        insert n word = setBit word n
        empty = 0 :: Int
```

The function looks for duplicate elements in a list of small integers.  The set `seen` is a representation of a set of small integers as a bit vector.  The profiler (run with `ghc -prof -auto-all`) claims that the `ok` function accounts for 22% of allocation overall.  Looking at the output with `-ddump-simpl`, I can't understand why this code is allocating.  I checked, and as far as I can tell it is *not* allocating a thunk for the call to `insert`.

What should I look at to identify the part of my code that is allocating?

Comment: Hard to judge without the rest of the code, but here are two possibilities.  `ok` has to allocate a new integer for every element.  unboxed ints are cheap, but if you're not allocating much else they could dominate.  Also, if the argument list is full of lazy values, `nodups` will force their evaluation, which could cause the allocation cost to be attributed here.  You may want to try using `+RTS -hc` or one of the other memory profiling options for more detailed information.

Comment: My prime suspect is that your list is full of lazy values that `nodups'` then forces. Try `deepseq`ing the list before to check whether that reduces the figures for `nodups'`.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know those guys are lazy.  But I guess I don't understand why the allocations get charged to `nodups'` instead of to the function where the cons's are.  (Actually those other two functions *are* the ones that get charged with the allocations.)  I will have to read the cost-center paper again.

Comment: The cost is allotted to the function that forces evaluation (at least, it used to be, Simon M. has changed a lot in the profiling code recently, maybe that changed), not necessarily the function that produces the thunk. The core of `nodups'` used unboxed `Int#`s wherever it could (with `-O2` of course), so that wouldn't allocate much by itself, unless it's called really really often.

Answer (score 1):

## Generally

I know of simple (scientific) implementations of functional languages, and if I remember correctly there is the [G-Machine](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/peytonjones92implementing.html) that may be used with Haskell.

This means (again, if I remember correctly) that your program state is represented like a "Tree", where the nodes are (for the sake of simplicity here) the functions you use in your code. The leafes would be the arguments to it. The "G-Maschine" then looks along the "Spine" (the left-side chain of nodes) and looks in the set of available "Functions" ("Supercombinators"?) for a pattern-match that it can apply. If a **mattern-match** is recognized from the **left side** of a definition it is then replaced by the **right side** of the definition.

This means that even a simple line like

```
ok seen (n:ns) = not (n `member` seen) && ok (n `insert` seen) ns
```

or even

```
(n:ns) = ns
```

is doing something in computer memory, i.e. matching the pattern

```
       ...
     ...
    (:)
   /   \
  n     ns
```

and replacing it with

```
       ...
     ...
    ns
```

The final result might consume less memory then the input, but this is a dynamic step and therefore must take place somewhere. If this is repeated over and over again (in a "tight loop") then this will make you CPU busy, as well it will your memory -- just because the G-Machine is operating. (As I said, I am not sure the G-Machine-concept applies here, but I guess it is something similar).

## Specific guesses

```
    member n word = testBit word n
    insert n word = setBit word n
```

Besides that I habe some suspicions. `testBit` and `setBit` look like index operations on lists. If they are it could take some work. If they are proper arrays it would be ok. If they are a sort of maps or sets... well... there might be costly hashing involved? Or implemented via a balanced tree, which uses lots of (costly?) comparision operations?

Comment: IIRc it is rather the spineless-tagless G-machine which is used. See the original paper http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=67083 for an introduction and how to implement a compiler for it.

Comment: `setBit` and `testBit` are bit operations, `setBit word n` is `word | (1 << n)`, `testBit word n` is `(word & (1 << n)) != 0`. Those are cheap and efficient.